# AMW ribbon cable

Tags: pcb, cables, cable-assemblies, ribbon-cable

I'm a software developer with a little hobby project involving an embedded system.

I have a debug board hooked up to another printed circuit board. The connection between the two boards is via this little ribbon cable as pictured below and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzqQX.jpg).  If you can't see the picture, the cable is a flat ribbon cable that is about a 1/2 cm wide, 10 pins, and has "AWM 20624 80C 60V VW-1" printed on it.

I started having some trouble with the debug board and observed that a couple of the exposed wires (pins) on the other side of the cable were starting to peel off or were bent back. So I'm searching for a replacement.

Googling for AWM 20624 mainly just yields a lot of E-Bay ads - mostly from Asia. And many have a different number of pin configurations. I was hoping to find the right one locally or by mail order in the US. Perhaps AWM is just a brand name and this type of cable has a more generic name that is more easily orderable.

Suggestions on how to obtain?

[image]

Comment: Why the aversion to china ebay shops?

Comment: @Passerby - because I would like to have product in my hands by the end of the week without paying extra for overseas shipping!

Comment: @selbie Interesting: From a quick scan, the price premium charged for FFC by Element14 and other sites seems to far exceed the cost of an eBay purchase with fast international shipping - not even taking into account the free-ship postal delivery options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Element14. Navigate from all products to "Cable, Wire & Assemblies" then "Cable Assemblies" and then finally "FFC / FPC (Flat Flex)" (http://au.element14.com/ffc-fpc-flat-flex). You can then select 10 connectors and the pitch spacing to 0.5mm and you should find what you need assuming the length is between 50mm to 229mm.

Comment: Thank you. I ultimately ordered from Digikey since it is in the USA and Element 14 appears to be in Australia. But the E14 site was very helpful in helping identify the appropriate item.